# How to change the Notification (Local or Push) tap behaviour in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, gesture-recognition

I want to change the notification tap behaviour. As we know that default behaviour of notification  is when we tap or touch on notification then it opens the app and when we press and hold (long press) the notification then its shows the notification preview (should become interactive notification) and we can interact through notification without opening the app.

But I want to reverse the default behaviour of notification i.e. when we tap or touch on the notification then it should open the notification preview (should become interactive notification) and we can interact through notification without opening the and when we press and hold the notification then it should open the app.  Could you please guild me how can I implement this notification feature.

Comment: You can't change the inbuilt behaviour of iOS notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is standardized behavior, and is the same along all apps.

If you do a quick skim of the documentation, you'll see there are no options for changing this.